# Вывод всех изображений из поддиректорий с лимитом и пагинацией

Tags: php

Как можно организовать вывод общей галереи фотографий, если имеется директория `images`, а в ней поддиректории с именем ID-пользователей, собственно в этих поддиректориях и находятся изображения.

```
glob('images/uploaded/' . $user_id . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE)
```

Как лимитировать получившийся массив, что бы можно было с помощью пагинации переходить к следующим 10 поддиректориям и выводить содержащиеся там изображения?

Comment: У меня будет своя галерея, с лимитом и пагинацией! (Извините, вырвалось).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [glob()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php) возвращает в результате массив. Дальше следует работать через функции работы с [массивами](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.array.php). Например, использовать функцию [array_slice()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php) для выбора среза массива.

Маленький пример (комментарии справа в примере):

```
$all_files = glob('images/uploaded/' . $user_id . '/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$all_pages = ceil(sizeof($all_files) / 10);                                                      // 10 изображений на страницу
$p = (!isset($_GET['p']) || $_GET['p'] < 1 || $_GET['p'] > $all_pages) ? 1 : intval($_GET['p']); // в адресной строке параметр p является номером страницы
$start_from = 10 * ($p - 1);
$files = array_slice($all_files, $start_from, 10);                                               // 10 элементов с нужной страницы
```